# What is the maximum len to recv/recvfrom

Tags: c, linux, sockets, buffer, recvfrom

When I listen to TCP or UDP socket with

`ssize_t recv(int sockfd, void *buf, size_t len, int flags);`

Or

`ssize_t recvfrom(int sockfd, void *buf, size_t len, int flag , struct sockaddr *src_addr, socklen_t *addrlen);`

There is argument called `len`

In linux ,what is the maximum buffer len that I can read with those function?is that 65336 ? Where is that defines?

What will happen if in socket there are more bytes than this number? They will dropped out? Or I will read them in the next loop?

Comment: What kind of socket?  UNIX, UDP, TCP?

Comment: Of course `len` is limited to `SIZE_MAX`, so the maximum is not higher than that.

Comment: SIZE_MAX in 32 bits system is 65336? Is that the maximum buffer len can I read from socket? What will happend if there is more data than this limit?

Answer (score 2):

Since `len` is of type `size_t`, its maximum size is defined by `SIZE_MAX`.
The C standard specifies that SIZE_MAX must be at least 65535.
However, there is no upper bound, so its actual value depends on the compiler.

`size_t` and `SIZE_MAX` are defined in `<stdint.h>`.

What will happen if there are more bytes than the specified `len` depends on what type of socket you have.

If you have a TCP socket (of type `SOCK_STREAM`), if there are more bytes waiting to be read than the value of `len`, then they will be read the next time you call `recv()`.

However, if your socket is of type `SOCK_DGRAM` (an UDP socket), a call to `recvfrom()` will always read an entire datagram. If the datagram's length is larger than `len`, the first `len` bytes will be read into your buffer and the rest will be lost.

In this case, `recvfrom()` returns -1 and sets errno to EMSGSIZE, so that's how you test if this happened.

Answer (score 0):

In theory, you can read as large of a buffer as you want.  The maximum value of `size_t` is guaranteed by the C standard to be at least 65535, however on modern Linux systems it will be at least 2<sup>32</sup>-1, if not 2<sup>64</sup>-1.

For TCP, since it is a streaming protocol, any bytes left unread will remain in the buffer waiting to be read on the next iteration.

For UDP, only one full datagram is read at a time, and if the buffer isn't big enough to hold a datagram any excess bytes are lost.  Additionally, because UDP doesn't have reliability built in to the protocol, datagrams can be lost if not read quickly enough.